# Angular. Класс как метод другого класса

Tags: angular2, typescript

Начал изучить Angular2 и встала следующая задача:
я создаю компонент info, в файле info.component.ts я задаю объекты следующиего вида:

```
import { Comm } from '../shared/comments';
...
const VASACOM: Comm = {
  name: 'Vasa',
  id: 122,
  comments: [
    {
     rating: 5,
     comment: "Some commment",
     date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
    },
    {
     rating: 4,
     comment: "Other comment",
     date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
    }
  ]
};
```

В comments.ts класс описываю так:

```
export class Comm {
  name: stirng;
  id: number;
  comments: Comment[];
  constructor(name:string,id:number,comments:Comment[]){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.comments = comments;
  }
}

export class Comment {
  rating: number;
  comment: string;
  date: string;
}
```

В итоге получаю:

> error TS2322: Object literal may only specify know properties, and 'comments' does not exist in type 'Comm'

Подскажите, что я сделал не так.

P.s. я понимаю, что можно создавать по отдельности 2 объекта, один класса Comm, другой Comment, но мне хочется делать это одним объектом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, уже подсказали. Мне помогло декларирование. В файле comments.ts я описал класс следующим образом:

```
export class Comm {
  constructor(
     public name: string,
     public id: number,
     public comments: Comment[]
   ){}
}

export class Comment {
   constructor(
     public rating: number,
     public comment: string,
     public date: string
   ){}
}
```